# Accessing symbol table in .class files

Tags: java, bytecode, symbol-table

For an arbitrary code base in Java, I want to create a table (conceptually) of USES and USED-BY relations between symbols and types. A symbol table has the information I need. However, writing a front end seems like a huge task and threatens to turn  my project into an even bigger sub-project. There's no reason for this, it seems to me ,because bytecode, the Java .class file necessarily contains within it such a symbol table for each class so that it can resolve types and references.

My question is -

> How can I programmaticly  access the symbol table  inside a set of
>   .class files so that I can create the USES / USED-BY table I want? Has
>   anyone already done  this (surely the answer is yes) and is the tool
>   to do this  not already a library ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ASM bytecode manipulation framework](http://asm.ow2.org). This [tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) has an example of dependencies retrieval from the bytecode. Though it can be significantly simplified if you use more recently introduced [RemappingClassAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/RemappingClassAdapter.html).

Comment: Yeah I am aware of ASM bytecode framework and I will probably end up using it, but I guess my question is, do you happen to know of all the many paper written about using it, some of which are available  on their site, if any cover doing just this- extracting information from the symbol table in the bytecode? OR is there a better way to do what it is I want to do? TIA

Comment: My old tutorial covers extraction of dependent classes, I've added a link to my answer. The problem with "symbol table" (it is actually called constant pool) is that it is out of context and you can't tell where constant is used from and what for.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the bytecode with [`javap`](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/javap-Disassemble-Java-Bytecode-Class-Files.html) , after that it is just text parsing.