# What is the equivalent in Java for "*.PDB" files in C#?

Tags: java, symbols, pdb-files

In C# I used to have symbols files (`*.PDB`) when compiling in debug mode which help winDbg and other debugging tools to monitor the application. 
But with Java, I couldn't find any way to create those symbol files. 
Is it possible with Java?

Comment: No. Debug is handled by the JDK, no PDB files needed (everything is inside the compiled app), you simply debug the app via JDK and add your breakpoints where you need them. If you are using an IDE, any IDE supports this feature

Answer (score 5):

Java does not use symbol files. All the information is contained within the class file itself that has the bytecode, symbol tables with variables, etc.

For example, reading the following question you see in the answer (and link) how to access the sybols using a library: [Accessing symbol table in .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979102/accessing-symbol-table-in-class-files)

Comment: Although Java does not use symbol files, it is possible to compile classes with more (or less) debug information.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Nevermind I found the answer to the previous comment. Mostly line numbers for stacktraces.

Comment: You can specific source (name of the file iirc), lines (linenumbers) and vars (names of local variables) (default is source and lines), see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html under `-g`